# How to center ElevatedButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I imported [sliding up panel][2] from pub.dev and everything is good except for one issue. I'm looking for a way to center the 'blue circle' vertically. (in between 'red appbar' and 'buttom slider') I tried wraping the code with 'center' or using mainaxisalignment but it doesn't work. Other things I tried which I found on google just gave me an errors. Please help.
Thanks in advance

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(200),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(100))
      ),
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          'Red AppBar',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 50.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: SlidingUpPanel(
    renderPanelSheet: false,
    panel: _floatingPanel(),
    collapsed: _floatingCollapsed(),
    body: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Blue Circle'),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ),
    )
  ),
);

  Widget _floatingCollapsed() {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0), topRight: Radius.circular(24.0)),
  ),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 0.0),
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      "buttom slider",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
  Widget _floatingPanel() {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: 20.0,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ]
  ),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
  child: Center(
    child: Text("LEVEL INFO"),
  ),
);
```

}

Also, what could be the best way to give margin to the 'blue circle' so it won't touch the far left and far right side of the screen?

Comment: Have you tried using a center widget?

Comment: I did. I used center widget on ElevatedButton and also the Text and nothing worked. I'm so confused not because it's hard to solve but I have no clue what the problem is...

Comment: Can you include `_floatingPanel` and  `_floatingCollapsed`

Comment: I included the _floatingPanel and _floatingCollapsed!

Comment: When I change the 'preferredSize: Size.fromHeight' at AppBar, the 'blue circle' moves. I'm guessing the 'Red AppBar' is pushing it?

Comment: Have you also tried to use Column with main axis as center same as the cross axis inside the Slidepanel wrap the elevated botton with column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SlidingUpPanel`'s body is using `Stack`, also getting full screen size. You can check

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    alignment: widget.slideDirection == SlideDirection.UP
        ? Alignment.bottomCenter
        : Alignment.topCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      //make the back widget take up the entire back side
      widget.body != null
          ? AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _ac,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Positioned(
                  top: widget.parallaxEnabled ? _getParallax() : 0.0,
                  child: child ?? SizedBox(),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: widget.body,
              ),
            )
```

You can play with [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) on `body` and wrapping with `SizedBox`. You can use `LayoutBuilder` or `MediaQuery` to provide size.

```dart
body: SlidingUpPanel(
    renderPanelSheet: false,
    panel: _floatingPanel(),
    collapsed: _floatingCollapsed(),
    body: Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0.0, -.3), //play with it
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: ElevatedButton(
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed Alignmentto Alignment.topcenter and it worked! but now I'm looking for a way to give some space between 'Red AppBar' and 'Blue Circle' using sizedbox? I guess. Have a good one!

Comment: You can use `Padding(top:`

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of sliding_up_panel, the body represents the widget that lies underneath the sliding panel and it automatically sizes itself to fill the screen. So it occupies full screen. Since you expanded AppBar to 200 unit, the body Widget was pushed down, hence you are seeing the centre point also pushed down by 200 unit. If you change the body height to occupy full screen from the start, by setting the Scaffold property extendBodyBehindAppBar with true, you will place the widget in the correct centre point.

if you add the below line immediately after the Scaffold. You will get desired result.

```
return Scaffold(
   extendBodyBehindAppBar:true,
```